# Difference between SQLAlchemy Select and Query API

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm

Not sure if this has been asked before, but in the SQLAlchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html#unified-tutorial) they talk about introducing `select()` as part of the new `2.0 style` for the ORM.
Previously (`1.x style`), the `query()` method were used to fetch data.
What is the difference between these two?

For example, for querying a `Users` table for a user with email and name we can do something as followed in Query API:

```py
session.query(Users).filter_by(name='name', email='mail@example.com').first()
```

In Select API, the same leads to more code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import select

query = select(Users).filter_by(name='name', email='mail@example.com')
user = session.execute(query).fetchone()
```

Is there any significant advantage of using one compared to other, for example, a performance boost?
2.0 API is still in active development yet it seems like their documentation is favoring the select API more than the "legacy" query API. Is this merely attempting to bridge the gap between the ORM and Core functionalities?

Answer (score 15):

The biggest difference is how the `select` statement is constructed. The new method creates a [`select` object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) which is more dynamic since it can be constructed from other select statements, [without explicit subquery definition](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#selectable-foundational-constructors):

```py
# select from a subqeuery styled query
q = select(Users).filter_by(name='name', email='mail@example.com')
q = select(Users.name, Users.email).select_from(q)
```

The outcome is more "native sql" construction of querying, as per the latest [selectable API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select). Queries can be defined and passed throughout statements in various functionalities such as where clauses, having, select_from, intersect, union, and so on.

Performance wise, probably some slight benefit in python run time (compiling of query), but negligible compared to network latency + db work.

> Great question btw! My response is informed by my experience with the select API. I am curious to hear what others have to say.

Comment: My full support on this last statement - I just stumbled over the same question and am really looking forward for more info on the matter. Thanks for this response!

Comment: Also, one of the big changes in the 2.0 version is the deep integration of type hinting (PEP 484), which should make the development much easier when using IDEs.

Answer (score 5):

Since 1.4 SQLAlchemy internally has implemented query() by the select() API, so in terms of performance there should be very little difference.

> In version 1.4, all Core and ORM SELECT statements are rendered from a
> Select object directly; when the Query object is used, at statement
> invocation time it copies its state to a Select which is then invoked
> internally using 2.0 style execution.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#change-5159

Historically the difference between query() and select() was query() was used for ORM and select() for Core. Version 2.0 removes many differences between ORM and Core and makes working with them more uniform. Comparing select() and query() doesn't really make sense anymore.

Although there is some backwards compatibility and you're not forced to adopt the 2.0 style immediately, I think it's wise to start adopting it, both in 1.4 and 2.0. I've been doing so for a while now and found it easy to get used to and soon more intuitively compared to the 1.x style. But I've been using SQLAlchemy only for about a year now and have many more years experience with native SQL.

Answer (score -2):

A "dumb" answer to this question is

- the newer `select().where()` method is hard to use
- the older `query().filter_by()` method is easy to use

Let me explain by way of an example:

```
'''
    This demonstrates the "old" way of querying
'''

#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sqlalchemy import Engine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import select

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class SimpleTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'simple_table'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    number: Mapped[int]


def main():

    url = 'postgresql://postgres:password@ipaddress/postgres'
    engine = create_engine(url)

    create_tables(engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:

        simple_table_rows = session \
            .query(SimpleTable) \
            .filter_by(name='name1') \
            .all()

        for simple_table_row in simple_table_rows:
            print(f'name: {simple_table_row.name}, number: {simple_table_row.number}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Contrast this with the new way, where we need an extra `simple_table_row = simple_table_row[0]` statement to convert a tuple containing only a single element into the type we actually wanted. (Which is `SimpleTableRow`.)

```
# Do not format: Indentation for easy of Copy&Paste

'''
    This demonstrates the "new" way of querying
'''

    with Session(engine) as session:

        simple_table_rows = session.execute(
            select(SimpleTable)
            .where(SimpleTable.name=='name1')
        ).all()

        for simple_table_row in simple_table_rows:

            simple_table_row = simple_table_row[0]

            print(f'name: {simple_table_row.name}, number: {simple_table_row.number}')
```

We can check that the returned "thing" is indeed a tuple.

```
# Do not format: Indentation for easy of Copy&Paste

        for simple_table_row in simple_table_rows:

            print(type(simple_table_row))
            print(f'')

            for d in dir(simple_table_row):
                if not d.startswith('__'):
                    print(d)
```

which prints this output:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>

_abc_impl
_asdict
_data
_fields
_filter_on_values
_get_by_key_impl_mapping
_is_protocol
_key_to_index
_mapping
_op
_parent
_special_name_accessor
_t
_to_tuple_instance
_tuple
_values_impl
count
index
t
tuple
```

I am not 100% on why the additional "get 0 index element of tuple" is required.

I would guess that the new `select()` syntax allows for more sophisticated querying of the database, for example by selecting multiple objects at once, perhaps as part of a join or something.

For most simple usecases however, it isn't needed and is just a source of an additional minor inconvenience of having to remember to call `row = row[0]`.

I suggest you use the "old" style for most cases.

One major issue with SQL Alchemy is how complicated it is as a libary.

There is usually more than one way of completing some task when writing code. However, there is usually only one "obvious" good way.

With SQL ALchemy there are a multitude of different ways of doing the exact same thing and the documentation doesn't really do much to explain which way is the most sensible approach.

It tells us there is an "old" way of doing it and a "new" way, and also an "older older way" which only works with version 1.4, etc etc...

The documentation is very long, but I'm not sure its great length does much in the way of helping us to understand how to perform common operations, which should be relatively simple.

Comment: Use `session.scalars(select(Model))` to get model instances without the tuple wrappers - [see here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html#simple-select).